# Open port 8080 on 14.04

Tags: iptables

I need to insert into iptables to open 8080.

With the iptables I looked at `iptables -L` it is so complicated and has many division I am not sure where to put the rule to open the port.

Here is my `iptables -L` output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_external (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_external_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_external_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_external_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDO_external_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDO_external_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_external_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_dmz (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_dmz_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_dmz_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_dmz_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_dmz_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW

Chain IN_dmz_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_dmz_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_external (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_external_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_external_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_external_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_external_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW

Chain IN_external_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_external_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_home (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_home_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_home_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_home_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_home_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ipp ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm ctstate NEW

Chain IN_home_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_home_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_internal (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_internal_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_internal_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_internal_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_internal_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ipp ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm ctstate NEW

Chain IN_internal_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_internal_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_work (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_work_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_work_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_work_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_work_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ipp ctstate NEW

Chain IN_work_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_work_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: You need to look at using ufw - uncomplicatedfirewall.

Comment: Why do you have a REJECT ALL at the end of INPUT and FORWARD chains, both of them with default policy ACCEPT, instead changing the default policy to REJECT? I bet those rules were created using some software (like e.g. [Firewall Builder](http://www.fwbuilder.org)). If this is your case, you should take a look at that program, it would be quite straightforward to set up there. Can you investigate who and how created those rules?

Comment: Also if you have a GUI in your system, you can try `gufw` (a very simple GUI to `ufw`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an iptables expert, but looking at your configuration the answer is: *nowhere*.

The second line, both in INPUT and FORWARD chains, seems to be allowing all from anywhere to anywhere, so explicitly adding a rule for a specific protocol and port number doesn't make much sense.